Symfony's user login magic in WebTestCase not working
As described in the documentation, I try to log-in the user in a WebTestCase:

class CreateStoreTest extends AbstractCrudTestCase
{

    // ...

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $userRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(AppUser::class);
        $testUser = $userRepository->findOneByEmail('user@domain.de');
        $this->client->loginUser($testUser);
    }

    // ...


When I try to fetch the user from the current security.token_storage, there is a user object, the following test succeeds:
    public function testIndex(): void
    {
        $token = $this->client->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage');
        $user = $token->getToken()->getUser();

        self::assertInstanceOf(AppUser::class, $user);
    }

But when I request the /dashboard url, the test failes:
    public function testIndex(): void
    {
        $this->client->request("GET", '/dashboard');

        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }

In the logs I see the authenticator is not supported:
[2024-05-24T12:27:27.321169+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking for authenticator support. {"firewall_name":"frontend","authenticators":1} []
[2024-05-24T12:27:27.321253+00:00] security.DEBUG: Checking support on authenticator. {"firewall_name":"frontend","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AppUserAuthenticator"} []
[2024-05-24T12:27:27.321321+00:00] security.DEBUG: Authenticator does not support the request. {"firewall_name":"frontend","authenticator":"App\\Security\\AppUserAuthenticator"} []
[2024-05-24T12:27:27.345638+00:00] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /srv/app/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:87)"} []
[2024-05-24T12:27:27.346294+00:00] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. {"entry_point":{"App\\Security\\AppUserAuthenticator":[]}} []

Here is the Authenticator:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\CsrfTokenBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\RememberMeBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityRequestAttributes;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AppUserAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    public function __construct(private UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        /** @var string $email */
        $email = $request->request->get('email', '');

        $request->getSession()->set(SecurityRequestAttributes::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        /** @var string $password */
        $password = $request->request->get('password', '');

        /** @var string $csrfToken */
        $csrfToken = $request->request->get('_csrf_token');

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge($email),
            new PasswordCredentials($password),
            [
                new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $csrfToken),
                new RememberMeBadge(),
            ],
        );
    }

    /** @phpcsSuppress SlevomatCodingStandard.Functions.UnusedParameter */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        $targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName);

        if (null !== $targetPath) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('dashboard_index'));
    }

    /** @phpcsSuppress SlevomatCodingStandard.Functions.UnusedParameter */
    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
}

And the content of the security.yaml:
security:
  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
  password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

  enable_authenticator_manager: true

  # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
  providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    app_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\AppUser
    backoffice_user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\BackofficeUser
        property: email
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false

    backoffice:
      pattern:   ^/backoffice
      lazy: true
      provider: backoffice_user_provider
      custom_authenticator:
        - App\Security\BackofficeAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: backoffice_logout

    frontend:
      pattern:   ^/
      lazy: true
      provider: app_user_provider
      custom_authenticator:
        - App\Security\AppUserAuthenticator
      logout:
        path: app_logout

  access_control:
    - { path: ^/backoffice/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/backoffice, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }

when@test:
  security:
    password_hashers:
      # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
      # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
      # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
      # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
      Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
        algorithm: auto
        cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
        time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
        memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon

In the dev-environtment (by clicking through the browser) both logins are working as expected.
Is there any magic only for the test-environment? If yes, where?
EDIT:
This is the whole test. The class extends AbstractCrudTestCase from EasyAdminBundle (but it's still a WebTestCase, see https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/tests.html):
<?php

namespace App\Tests\IntegrationTests\Dashboard;

use App\Controller\Dashboard\DashboardController;
use App\Controller\Dashboard\StoreCrudController;
use App\Entity\AppUser;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Test\AbstractCrudTestCase;

class CreateStoreTest extends AbstractCrudTestCase
{

    protected function getControllerFqcn(): string
    {
        return StoreCrudController::class;
    }

    protected function getDashboardFqcn(): string
    {
        return DashboardController::class;
    }

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $userRepository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(AppUser::class);
        $testUser = $userRepository->findOneByEmail('user@xyz.tld');
        $this->client->loginUser($testUser);
    }

    public function testIndex(): void
    {
        $this->client->request("GET", '/dashboard');

        self::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
}


There is no magic :) How do you login to your app in your test ? I see your backoffice is protected with ROLE_USER

As you can see in the security.yaml, /backoffice is protected by the role ROLE_ADMIN, not ROLE_USER. If you read the first code block, you see how the login happens in the test.

Can you provide the full code of your test please. You could debug in the AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator->support method why your authenticator is not taking the request. Are you using the same http client that you used to login?

The whole test class has been added.

at this point (AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator->support), the loginUrl must be /dashboard, to get true as return value, but its false, because /dashboard!==/login` - IMHO this check makes no sense...
